# bootstrap modal button surrounding other html not working in firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have created some image hover effects for all to use. I am using bootstrap modals so you can click show code and the pop up will appear with the html and css you can simply copy and paste. However on some of the effects do not contain text and show font icons instead. For these examples I put the font icons inside the button and changed the style of the button. This works fine in chrome, you can click around the icons and the modal opens up. However in firefox it does not work at all is anyone able to help?

For example here is the code for effect 7. Works fine in chrome but not in firefox:

```
<button class="emptybutton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal7">
                        <h2>Hover effect 7</h2>
                        <p>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
                        </p>
</button>
```

To view the live version go here: https://miketricking.github.io/

Thank you all in advance! :)

Comment: A div, a h, a p and some anchors walk into a button...You can't nest these elements inside a button...make a div instead of the button, see how that works

Comment: But the modal only works as a button not a div

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if anyone encounters the same issue you can actually use other elements to open a modal. All you have to do it give the data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal7" attributes to a different element and it should work.

Here is my updated code:

```
<div class="overlay point" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal7">
    <h2>Hover effect 7</h2>
    <p>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
    </p>
</div>
```